# Android firebase database get values totals

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My database looks like:]

I'm using firebase-realtime-database, I want to get all total child values and total child name.

I need to get all total values and total amount
if I add new item, that item total also addition to all totals.

Comment: So you want to get the total of all objects beneath `OrderItemLsit` -> `01`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener)

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
         YourModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);

         // declare a global variable total
         total += model.getTotal();
    }
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
});
```

Comment: what is the total datatype?

Comment: It depends on what you specify in your model.

Comment: The above code might not work , The best thing  to do is create a separate node for saving total values, and during insertion of each item update the value of total in the database using transaction function in firebase realtime database. For large data the above mentioned code willl load more data and time,

Comment: @JinsonPaul Thanks for sharing your opinion.

But i disagree, creating another node for the total value is fine, but now you just added another job because every transaction now needs to synchronize or update the **total** node. So IMHO a better way is to listen for Child Events and store the total value with a local variable rather than creating a node with a value that has a chance of desynchronization.

Comment: But the problem arises when the app is closes then the local value get reset to 0 , childadded executes each time when a new child is added to the db. So if the data becomes too large and when the user uninstalls his app and then install the user need to fetch the whole data from database, Instead if we set a separate node for saving total , it remains there , I strongly recommend this method  since I experienced issues by calculating data each time. And it is both time and data consuming

Comment: @JinsonPaul Sure, each of our method works and has its advantages and disadvantages. Please post your answer so we can help the **OP**